# Bootstrap inline form - how to use fixed widths / spans?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have two or more rows with three checkboxes in each row.  I would like them to line up evenly between the rows like they are in table columns.  Right now they look staggered depending on the length of the text label.  How can I simulate table columns for each row so that the layout looks more organized?

```
<form id="form-filter" name="form-filter" method="POST" action="/filter" class="form-inline">
                  <fieldset>
                    <legend style="margin-bottom:-10px;">Select up to 6 filters</legend>
                    <div class="control-group">
                      <div class="controls">
                        <label class="checkbox inline">
                          <input id="Medjugorje" name="Medjugorje" type="checkbox" checked>Medjugorje
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox inline">
                          <input id="Kibeho" name="Kibeho" type="checkbox">Kibeho
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox inline">
                          <input id="Lourdes" name="Lourdes" type="checkbox">Lourdes
                        </label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="controls">
                        <label class="checkbox inline">
                          <input id="Fatima" name="Fatima" type="checkbox">Fatima
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox inline">
                          <input id="Secrets" name="Secrets" type="checkbox">Secrets
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Filter</button>
                    <button id="clearButton" type="button" class="btn">Clear</button>
                  </fieldset>
                </form>
```

Comment: why don't use `row-fluid` and `span`'s like [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HYmpB4U00UDb57E58Dg1?p=preview), you need to expand the width of the preview frame because of the responsive nature

Comment: That example shows 6 checkboxes in a single column.  I am looking for the 6 checkboxes split across 3 columns and 2 rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="form-filter" name="form-filter" method="POST" action="/filter">
                  <fieldset>
                    <legend>Select up to 6 filters</legend>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                      <div class="span12">
                        <label class="checkbox span4">
                          <input id="Medjugorje" name="Medjugorje" type="checkbox" checked>Medjugorje
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox span4">
                          <input id="Kibeho" name="Kibeho" type="checkbox">Kibeho
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox span4">
                          <input id="Lourdes" name="Lourdes" type="checkbox">Lourdes
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                      <div class="span12">
                        <label class="checkbox span4">
                          <input id="Fatima" name="Fatima" type="checkbox" checked>Fatima
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox span4">
                          <input id="Banneux" name="Banneux" type="checkbox">Banneux
                        </label>
                        <label class="checkbox span4">
                          <input id="Beauraing" name="Beauraing" type="checkbox">Beauraing
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Filter</button>
                    <button id="clearButton" type="button" class="btn">Clear</button>
                  </fieldset>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="form-filter" name="form-filter" method="POST" action="/filter">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            Select up to 6 filters
        </legend>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span4">

                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input id="Medjugorje" name="Medjugorje" type="checkbox" checked>
                    Medjugorje </label>
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input id="Kibeho" name="Kibeho" type="checkbox">
                    Kibeho </label>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">

                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input id="Lourdes" name="Lourdes" type="checkbox">
                    Lourdes </label>
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input id="Fatima" name="Fatima" type="checkbox" checked>
                    Fatima </label>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">

                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input id="Banneux" name="Banneux" type="checkbox">
                    Banneux </label>
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input id="Beauraing" name="Beauraing" type="checkbox">
                    Beauraing </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            Filter
        </button>
        <button id="clearButton" type="button" class="btn">
            Clear
        </button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```